# Querying XML Data Using SQL Parameters

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to query XML data in a table using a SQL parameter containing the *search* criteria and I am getting unexpected results.

As an example, consider the following T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Configuration AS TABLE
(
    [Data] XML NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Configuration ([Data]) VALUES '<Configuration><Colors><Color>RED</Color><Color>BLUE</Color></Colors></Configuration>');

DECLARE @Color AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Color = N'YELLOW';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Configuration WHERE [Data].exist('/Configuration/Colors/Color/text() = sql:variable("@Color")') = 1;
```

I would expect the result of this query to return 0.  In fact, this query returns 1.  Even worse, it appears to return one regardless of what value I set `@Color` to.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missing `[` in your query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Configuration WHERE [Data].exist('/Configuration/Colors/Color[text() = sql:variable("@Color")]') = 1;
```

`XPath` expressions are supposed to be enclosed between `[` and `]`.  For more information on `XPath` and writing expressions, please refer [this tutorial page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: Any idea what the actual semantics are of the query in the OP? What is it actually evaluating the `exist` against?

Comment: @MartinSmith I believe he is trying to find if the given parameter value exists in the XML

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. I asked what the query is currently doing. As it doesn't raise any error. Is it just basically evaluating the existence of a Boolean result?

Comment: @MartinSmith Not sure what you are asking; Please fill-in additional details whatever I have misunderstood or incorrectly answered; I was only concerned to fix the issue he had

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked either (perhaps I left some detail off of my original question).  The answer provided here is what I was looking for.  As such, I have marked it as the accepted solution.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect. It's just the OP's current query appears to have valid syntax but incorrect semantics, so I'm asking what the semantics actually are. Looks like none of us know so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @MartinSmith - If I understand you correctly, I hope you are looking for the reason for not getting an error when OP omitted braces... Is it so? or Why did it evaluate to 1 always when there was an error?

Comment: Yes. I imagine it might be doing `'/Configuration/Colors/Color/text() = sql:variable("@Color")'` and evaluating as a Boolean result and then just checking whether a result exists for example. And irrespective of whether the result is true or false it still exists.

Comment: true... that's little baffling; `'/Configuration/Colors/Color/text()` should actually retrieve all values and compare against the variable;